# Setting default setting for all jQuery-UI datepicker instances

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, zend-framework

I am using jQuery-UI [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) (via [ZendX](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zendx.jquery.view.html) view helper) to select dates. Now I would like to set default settings (setDefaults) which sets default setting for all Datepicker instances.

This is how my form looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="/hello/world">
  <?php
    echo $this->datePicker("dp1",'',array(
                                        'defaultDate' =>date('Y m d',time()),
                                        'showWeek' => 'true',
                                        'firstDay' => 1,
                                        'dateFormat' => 'dd.mm.yy',
                                        'changeYear' => 'true',
                                        'changeMonth' => 'true'
                                        ));

    echo $this->datePicker("dp2",'',array());
  ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Does someone know how to set this when using Zend Framework?

Thanks, Udo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend the DataPicker View Helper class (or what ever it is called) and create your own constructor. Then use that custom class...